# Grafana to use aggregration for total of two field sums of Elasticsearch data source

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

1. I have two fields lets say the name is 
   `{"apple":100} and {"orange: 50"}`
2. I want to use the Grafana metrics to have the total sum of both "apple" and "orange"
3. I've tried to use multiple sum metrics but that doesn't add up the both field sums.
4. After going through discussion/questions posted online i still unable to find the exact solution.

Answer (score 5):

[image: add_two_fields_value_by_using_script]
I've found the answer, we need to utilize the "Script" option. 
First we set a metric to get sum of apple, then the result of sum of apple is added to doc["orange"].value

In the script i wrote something like this 
_value + doc["orange"].value

and the value return in the graph is correct! :D